# Where can I find the syscall-number mapping table/file in Ubuntu 11.04 (x86)?

Tags: kernel

I know 11.04 is an old release but a project I'm working on demands that I map some syscalls with their syscall-numbers. Were can I find the syscall-to-number table/file in ubuntu 11.04 (x86).

Edit: I want to be able to extract the following mapping from the file:

Number....................................Syscall

x............................................sys_readv

y.............................................sys_stat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found them in my ubuntu 14.04 here:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25/include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Shiva, thanks, its what I'm looking for. For Ubuntu 11.04, I found it in /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-8/include/asm-generic.unistd.h

Comment: I am glad that I could be of help. I just read about it in a book(Operating System Principles by Galvin) as I am starting to learn operating systems. It was just mentioned there and I didnt know what to do with it. Can you tell me some good book to learn operating systems with practical implementations or a good online course? Thanks.:)

Comment: good suggestions have been given for your question on Quora.  For the good online courses, checkout [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-good-online-course-for-operating-systems-being-offered). For the book(s) see [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-book-on-operating-systems)

Answer (score 0):

You can find it on the Ubuntu website [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man2/syscalls.2.html).

Comment: Hi Trevor, I added an edit in the question on the kind of mapping I want to make from the file. The link you sent doesn't have the number just the syscalls

Comment: Is it not in the file at the very top of the page

Comment: Trevor can you paste the hyper-link to the file you are referring to or the name? Thanks

Comment: Is it not this http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages.gz/hardy/man2/syscalls.2.gz

Comment: that file just lists syscals, but not the syscall numbers. The numbers 2.x or 2.x.x is the kernel versions. But for a particular system (x64 or x86), their is a syscall number for all syscalls. See e.g: [https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/](https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/)

Comment: @TrevorClarke, this is not a syscall mapping table

Answer (score 0):

I was working on something on SEEDLabs, which is Ubuntu 16.04.1.

I found a list of the syscall numbers here :`/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_32.h`

Also, here is an output of my system information (ignore the date):

```
uname -a
Linux VM 4.8.0-36-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sun Feb 5 09:39:41 UTC 2017 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux
```